# eav_entity_type without quote at installation

Tags: php, magento, installation, entity-attribute-value, quote

**the origin...**

I have a module with a setup script (common mysql4-upgrade-0.1.0-0.1.1.php), adding an attribute to quote:

```
$eav = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('sales_setup');
$eav->addAttribute('quote', 'my_attribute', array('type' => 'varchar'));
```

If I run my magento store on an empty DB, setups scripts run and a 'Wrong entity ID' error breaks the process. Call stack points to my setup script.

**...looking for...**

If I go to database, I see **eav_entity_type** table filled but only with 8 types: the quote type is not registered!

That's why Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup->getEntityTypeId() throws the exception.

**The question:**

I don't know why quote entity is not created with another entities. How can I force magento to register quote entity before my module setup? Is there any alternative?

There is a [possibly related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7272879/magento-add-field-to-sales-flat-quote)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Starring from 1.4.x all the entities were moved in to flat structure. However it is still possible to use pseudo EAV interface of Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup class. Your code is not working because you are using Eav setup model instead of Sales one.

Also, by default all the module setup scripts in app/code/local/ are processed only after scripts in app/code/core, so you can choose to not specify dependency on core module.

Sincerely,
Ivan